# Resources for Building Dynamic Lift Shopping Cart?

Tags: ajax, scala, lift

Here's what I'd like to do with Lift:  I want to build a dynamic shopping cart, with lines able to be added and removed via AJAX calls.  The total needs to be wired to the specific lines.  Each line would include a number, the length of time for a lease, and a calculated price based on that, so I would have to add wired cells on each addable/removable line as well.  So it would look something like this:

```
Number          Length of Lease          Price                      Remove?
(AJAX Textbox)  (AJAX Dropdown Select)   (Plain Updateable Text)    (Ajax Checkbox)
(Another Row)...
+ Add 
Total: ______
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can find resources to build a static page that displays all of this via Wiring.  Using the Lift Demo site, I can pull up code that will let me add new lines, but it doesn't seem to me to be conducive to removing lines (this in general is one of my frustrations with Lift at the moment: a "little extra detail" to change from a tutorial ends up requiring me to completely change tacks and spend hours more at work and research, and I want to figure out how I'm probably approaching these problems wrongly!).  Alternatively, I can use CSS selectors to dynamically create content, but I don't know how to effectively wire these together.

In addition, all of my attempts end up creating 2-3 times the amount of code I would have written to simply do some JQuery updates on the page, so I suspect that I'm doing something wrong and overcomplicating everything.

What resources would people recommend to set me on the right path?

Comment: Are you using comet to push your dynamic updates to the client?

Comment: I'm not even at the point of trying to get stuff from the server yet.  I just want to know how to make the front-end work, first.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll gear my answer more towards the general question in your last sentence. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are your best resources for learning Lift:

1. [Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net/)
2. [Lift Cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000030/index.html)
3. [Lift in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182803)

For any specific questions, I *highly* recommend you join us at the [Lift Community Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb).  It is the official support channel for Lift.  Although a few of us occasionally help out here at Stackoverflow, the best Lift help can be found there.